# What is the CDE/Motif keyboard shortcut for selecting all the text in a text box?

Tags: solaris

What is the keyboard shortcut for selecting all the text in a text box in CDE (or Motif generally)?

In CDE, text boxes support Emacs/Readline style keyboard shortcuts, so for instance <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> moves the cursor the beginning of the line.  However Readline doesn't have a concept of a selection as far as I can tell, and Emacs' marking shortcuts don't seem to be supported.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>.

**Previous alternative:**

For now, the best I can come up with is to do the selection in multiple steps, using the navigation keys that work with <kbd>Shift</kbd> selection:

1. Go to the beginning of the text: <kbd>Home</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>←</kbd>
2. Hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> to do a selection
3. With <kbd>Shift</kbd> held down, go to the end of the text: <kbd>End</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>→</kbd>

This at least has the advantage that it works the same way in CDE, GTK+, and Qt apps.